# Looking for a surface function $f(x, y)$ like a sheet draped on a string

Tags: functions, surfaces

In an application, a solution may be available in 0 < x ≤ 25, 0 < y ≤ 25. To compare different solutions and choose an optimal one, I would like a function f(x, y) such that:

- $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$
- $f(x, k)$ for $0 < x ≤ 25$ has a maximum at $x=k$
- $f(k,y)$ for $0 < y ≤ 25$ has a maximum at $y=k$
- $f(x−k,y−k)>f(x,y)$ for $k > 0$

Imagine a pole at $(0,0)$, then tying a loose string to $(25, 25)$ at closer to ground level, then draping a sheet over that, so that the sheet forms a ridge from $(0,0)$ to $(25, 25)$ that tapers down to the sides.

Ideally $f$ would be continuous and not too computationally intensive.

Getting a local maximum at $f(0⁺
,0⁺)$ is easy enough, e.g. $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$, but I can’t seem to get the “ridge”.

Any suggestions would help, thank you.

Comment: Will this work for you? $\frac{50-x-y}{5+(x-y)^2}$

Comment: @VasilyMitch - Almost, but if you check f(x, 23) and f(23, y) for all x and y, the maxima are not at 23.

Comment: It's impossible to get what you ask then. If you calculate gradient and some point on the ridge, you are supposed to get something like $(-g, -g)$. Symmetric function growing in the direction to $(0,0)$. But then it means that $\partial f/\partial x\neq 0$, a condition needed for maximum at ridge

Comment: Or you can make non-smooth surface like $50-(x+y)-10|x-y|^{2/3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by some suggestions from Vasily Mitch, while not exactly computationally light, this one meets the criteria:

$$f(x, y) = -\log((x^2+y^2)(1+(x-y)^2))$$

The equivalent is “flipping” the problem around and using the minimum solutions of:

$$f(x, y) = (x^2+y^2)(1+(x-y)^2)$$

While it doesn’t have the striking features of the previous, it generates the same preferred solutions.

Edit: I found the function above too heavily biased for solutions along the ridge, so instead used:

$$f(x, y) = x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2$$

Which gives a much gentler bias to the ridge.